# Managing Limitations for amount of user operations in DynamoDB: Storing and Enforcing Limits

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I'm using a DynamoDB database where I need to store some information.
For example, let's say we need to store data for different users.
I've implemented a Spring Boot service that exposes some REST APIs to create, modify, or delete this data.

Now, for some reason, I need to implement a sort of limitation: I want to forbid these operations if a user has already reached a certain limit.

Let me explain it better:
Let's assume we need to store user devices' information, similar to the approach used for pay-per-view TV services.
We want to lock changes for a specific user if they have already reached the maximum allowed operations on their devices.
This means the user should not be able to register or delete devices once they have reached the limit within a specific interval of time.

For this specific example, we can assume that we are storing devices' information in a DynamoDB table. Now, the question is, how and where can I store the count of operations that the user has performed on their devices? Do I need to use a dedicated table? Would that be a good solution?"

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need a second table, you can use the same table, but either is suitable, which ever is preferable for you.

| PK | SK | data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| User1 | device1 | {} |
| User1 | device2 | {} |
| User1 | device3 | {} |
| User1 | DEVICES | 3 |

Now you can use `TransactWriteItems` when trying to add more devices, with a limitation of no more than 3 allowed:

```
tx1 ADD DEVICE
tx2 IF user.DECVICES < 3
```

In this scenario the operation would fail because user1 already has 3 devices.

Comment: Resuming the device example, I am currently storing device information in this table. Essentially, I have some fields that are filled for all rows and some fields that are different. For example:
For all rows, I have: ID, USER, F_A
For some rows, I also have F_B, F_C
I have also created some additional indexes based on this table structure.
Is it possible or reasonable to use the same table to store a completely different type of information (USER - OPERATION-COUNT)?
What will happen to the fields that I am considering for all rows?

Comment: It's reasonable if you think so and that it doesn't add complexity. It's totally fine to store in multiple tables, transactions can access multiple tables in a single request.